# Three js decals

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, decal

How can I add a decal to a 3d OBJ model in three js??

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
            loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
                object = event.content;
                scene.add(object);
            });

            loader.load('test.obj', 'test.mtl');
```

Comment: Can you explain your question more. The code listed does not help at all. It just loads a model.

Comment: So... How can I load a Texture to a given coordinates for an OBJ model

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to give position. As I do.
    var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event )
    {
        casa = event.content;
        casa.scale.x = casa.scale.y = casa.scale.z = 14.5;
        casa.position.y=-40;

```
    casa.updateMatrix();
    scene.add(casa);
});
loader.load(
        'entidades/entidad_1/obj_model/casa.obj',
        'entidades/entidad_1/obj_model/casa.mtl');
```